# Retrieve Greek letters from MSSQL database with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, character-encoding

I've done this before in .Net but I am somewhat new to PHP and could use some help.  I'm trying to pull data in PHP from a MSSQL db, some of which is Greek letters.  The data type of the MSSQL columns is `nvarchar` and the Greek characters are displayed correctly in management studio; however, whenever I pull the data with the `sqlsrv_query` function in php I get a bunch of question marks.

In `sqlsrv_connect` function I've tried setting `CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8` which doesn't work.
I've tried `iconv()`, but am not sure which sets to use.
I tried `mb_detect_encoding()` and it returned `ASCIIASCII`.

Here is some sample code:

```
public function _getOrderItemDetails($orderItemIds,$productTypeId){
    $params = explode(',', $orderItemIds);

    $sql = "select od.*, ofs.Sort
            from orderDetail od
                left join orderFieldSort ofs on ofs.fieldName = od.name and productTypeId in ($productTypeId)
            where orderItemid in (".rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($params)),',').")
            order by ofs.sort";

   return $this->_compileResults($sql,'OrderDetail',$params);;
}

private function _compileResults($sql,$classType,$params ){       
    $result = sqlsrv_query($this->conn,$sql,$params);

    $arrayResult = array();
    while($orderObject = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result,$classType)){
        array_push($arrayResult, $orderObject);
    }
    return $arrayResult;
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to maybe try.

1) Can you validate exactly what character encoding your DB is in?  I recommend UTF8 for everything as it should handle the widest range of characters. "ASCIIASCII" is not a character encoding to my knowledge do you mean "ASCII"?

2)Try using `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` changing the char set to match your db encoding.  It "Sets the default character set for the current connection." from within the current php script. [PHP official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

3)This is an outlier but where are you viewing the results?  Irrelevant of the data returned from your DB the if you are viewing the results in a web browser you will need to make sure the page has the appropriate charter encoding set in the head if this is a miss match from the character set returned from your db it can result in the question marks or diamonds...  Typically something like this

```
   <head>
    <title>page title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />   
   </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with you so when i was searching to find the solution i saw your question.The answer is very simple.I guess somewhere in your code you connect to the database with code like the following :

```
$serverName = "YOUR_SERVER";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"YourDatabase");
$link = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
if(!$link ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

To make greek characters show up you need to change line 2, from:

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"YourDatabase");
```

to :

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"YourDatabase","CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
```

and the rest code stays the same.
This solution was suggested by @Graham to his own question i think, and it is from here : [Greek character insertion in php compared to SQL server management studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698798/greek-character-insertion-in-php-compared-to-sql-server-management-studio)