# Greek character insertion in php compared to SQL server management studio

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a sql server table:

```
create table tmp (fname nvarchar(40))
```

I have a php script that inserts some Greek characters:

```
$cn = sqlsrv_connect(...

// insert greek chars
sqlsrv_query($cn, "INSERT INTO tmp (fname) VALUES (N'ΚΩΝΣΤΑΝΤΙΝΟΣ')");

// read them back again
$rs = sqlsrv_query($cn, "SELECT fname FROM tmp");
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rs, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);

// output result
print "<br />from database: " . $row[0];

sqlsrv_close($cn);
```

This works as expected (ie. greek in - greek out)

If I now use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

```
select * from tmp
```

I get:

```
ÎšÎ©ÎÎ£Î¤Î‘ÎÎ¤Î™ÎÎŸÎ£
```

If I do the insert using SSMS:

```
delete from tmp
INSERT INTO tmp (fname) VALUES (N'ΚΩΝΣΤΑΝΤΙΝΟΣ')
select * from tmp
```

I get:

```
ΚΩΝΣΤΑΝΤΙΝΟΣ
```

BUT if I access that from php:

```
$cn = sqlsrv_connect(...
$rs = sqlsrv_query($cn, "SELECT fname FROM tmp");
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rs, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
print "<br />from database: " . $row[0];
sqlsrv_close($cn);
```

I get:

```
?O?S???????S
```

I have tried `<meta charset="utf-8">` and `<meta charset="utf-16">` - makes no difference.

So - two questions:

**What is going on here?**

**How can I get consistency with both SSMS and php?**

I'm using:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64) 
    Oct 19 2012 13:38:57 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  11.0.2100.60

PHP 5.6.7
```

Comment: Check here: http://www.webr2.com/php-sql-server-how-to-set-charset-for-connection/

Answer (score 0):

It seems all I needed was the addition of `"CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8"` in my connection string.  I was thrown by the fact that other non-ASCII data has successfully been going into this database for ages without this addition.

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"mydatabase", "UID"=>"myuserid", "PWD"=>"mypassword", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
$cn = sqlsrv_connect("myserver", $connectionInfo);
...
```