# Retrieve Greek chars from MSSQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding

I am trying to retrieve data from an MSSQL Server using PHP and I have issues displaying the Greek characters. I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170653/retrieve-greek-letters-from-mssql-database-with-php) but there is no correct answer to it. I am connecting to my DB with mssql_connect and not with sqlsrv_connect as mentioned in the post above.

I also tried

```
mssql_query("SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),name))AS x FROM customers
```

with

```
mb_detect_encoding($row['x'], mb_detect_order(), true) === 'UTF-8' ? $row['x'] : mb_convert_encoding($row['x'], 'UTF-8');
```

that I found somewhere else but I am still getting ??????? instead of greek chars. Any idea?

Comment: is the datatype column `nvarchar` ?

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader I don't have access to the DB. The person in charge told me that it plain varchar

Comment: it should be `nvarchar`

Comment: Tried this and still not working. Any other idea?